# determining the number of digits in text file

Tags: scripts

I have a data file as follows:

```
 15 01 01 00 00  0.0000000  0 22E19R13R12G15G26G24G21E20R19G13G18G29
 15 01 01 01 00 30.0000000  0 22E19R13R12G15G26G24G21E20R19G13G18G29
 15 01 01 02 01  0.0000000  0 22E19R13R12G15G26G24G21E20R19G13G18G29
 15 01 01 03 01 30.0000000  0 22E19R13R12G15G26G24G21E20R19G13G18G29
```

I need to count the digit number of the value in the first line and fourth column then I need to determine this digit number as a variable as follows:

first line and fourth column: 00

```
digit_number=2
```

Comment: Would be stack overflow the perfect place for this question?

Comment: You can probably do this with `sed` and `awk`  `sed 's/[^0-9]//g' dat | awk '{ print length }'` I'm neither an expert in `sed` nor `awk` so I expect someone to tell me this is very wrong :-) (also this only counts up all the numbers rather than just the first line and fourth column, again not an awk expert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to actually check that the value is a number, you can simply check the *length* of the 4th *field* from the 1st *record*

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print length($4); exit}' file
```

To assign to a shell variable:

```
digit_number=$(awk 'FNR == 1 {print length($4); exit}' file)
```

---

If you need to count how many digits are in the field, then you could modify the awk command to

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print gsub(/[0-9]/,"",$4); exit}' file
```

Note that `gsub` will return a count of decimal digits `[0-9]` ignoring any non-digit characters in the field.

Answer (score 1):

```
digit_number=$(head -1 {the file} | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | tr -d '\n' | wc -c)
```

Where:

- `head -1 {the file}` print the first line of the file
- `cut -d ' ' -f 4` takes the 4th space-delimited field
- `tr -d '\n'` removes the trailing lf
- `wc -c` counts the bytes in the result